# Products and categories are not showing in frontend store

Tags: product

I am using magento version 1.9.2. I have added some products in appropriate categories, also mentioned the stock quantity and product is in "in stock". But still those products are not available in front-end store. So what to do???

Comment: try to check with product url.... as like siteurl/product-url.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **checklist** for whether items are in stock follows.

1. The products must be Visible in Catalog.
2. The products must be Enabled.
3. Product must have a stock Quantity.
4. The product must be set to In Stock.
5. If the product is set not to track stock, it still has to have a stock Quantity and be set to In Stock.
6. The product must be assigned to the target Category.
7. If using multi-website mode (or if you imported the products through Data Flow), the products must be assigned to the target Website.
8. Try by flusing magento cache in admin panel got `System->Cache Management-> Flush Magento cache` , then refresh the frontend , if it is still not worked go to `System->Index Management -> Select all` the indexes and `reindex` them and refresh the front end

Comment: Thanks a lot @Arjun. Btw where is your Gandib. lol... I am joking. btw thanks man for responding.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue with reindex

Do reindex from `system->index managment`

after that flush cache or delete `var/cache` folder

and check again

Please let me know if you still facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

Also, make reindex in admin panel - System->Index Management. This worked for me.